# В utf у одного символа много значений. Как найти символ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, текст, gpt, естественный-язык

Есть например, знак чёрточка - — – . Как определить все виды чёрточек в тексте и заменить на самую простую чёрточку - ? Или пробелы  _ . Как определить все виды пробелов и заменить их на _? Теперь знаки окончания предложения ! ? . ; Как определить все знаки окончания предложения?

1. Регулярка которая включает все возможные варианты?
2. ИИ? Нейросети?

Я просто хочу токенизировать текст для клавиатуры. Есть много чего, что может пойти не так. Почему это так сложно?

Comment: Вот тут https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html есть много юникодных категорий вида `\p{Pd}` и прочее. Не знаю, покроют ли они твои надобности. Ну и не все движки регулярных выражений эти классы поддерживают.